# php - parse single value to android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I try to write a simple php file, which checks, whether a mysql value exists or not.

For this, I need to parse a simple string from json to android.

e.g: when the value exists, the string is "yes" and when it doesnt exists the string is "no".

Meanwhile I have tried a lot of "solutions", but nothing works.

To do that I usually use this:

```
  $abfrage = "
SELECT
 Something
FROM
 somewhere
 WHERE
 This=$that"

 ;


$link = mysql_query($abfrage) OR die("Error:"+mysql_error());


while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($link)){
 $new=$line;

  }


print(json_encode($new));
```

and in Android:

```
try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
}     

try
    {
 System.out.println(result);


         json_data = new JSONObject(result);

         String name=(json_data.getString("something"));

     Log.e("pass 3", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("result:", result.toString());


        }

    }
```

This works well, an the the value of the String "name" is the value of "something".

**But now my question:**

***Is it possible to save a string in PHP and parse them to android?***

**This is what i got:**

```
 $abfrage = "SELECT Something FROM somewhere WHERE This = '$that' LIMIT 1";





// Proof whether the value exists or not

$read = mysql_db_query($db, $abfrage);     
 if (mysql_num_rows($read) == 0){

$value="no";
 }
else{
$value="yes";
};

  print json_encode($value);
```

And in JAVA:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/test.php");
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);



 String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
 System.out.println(""+str); //prints: yes


  if(str=="yes") System.out.println("ok"); //not called
  if(str=="no") System.out.println("nope"); //not called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced this problem months before:

**The problem is, that the String str, not only contains the word "yes". It also contains different letters/symbols, which are not displayed in Android/Eclipse. So you have to manually delete these letters by simply calling substring(int start, int end)**

Try this:

```
String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


    int number= str.length(); 
    System.out.println("str-length"+number); //You will see not the length of 3 (for    yes)

    String s2= str.substring(0, 3);  //short the string
    System.out.println("String s2"+s2);

   if(s2.equals("yes"))Log.d("Titles", str);
```

Comment: That is something strange! So I guess there is something added when value is sent. I think that there must be the way to deal with it, not by manually deleting symbols.

Comment: This is the only way I know, to deal with it. But in general there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you implemented it, but I assume that you execute PHP script from java code with something like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/sample/sample.php");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Then simply use:

```
String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Use

```
Log.d("Title", "Message");
```

To display messages in Logcat console.

Comment: so I guess my answer is OK. Just use the code I provided. If you echo something from `test.php`, it should be returned and 'saved' in `response`. Just parse it to string (last line) and that's it - `str` should contain value of `$value` from PHP script

Comment: tested, It works and the value of str is "yes", but unfortunatley I cannot work with this. Example: if(str=="yes") {this is never called);

Comment: please update code samples with your current code and this `if` statement that is not working

Comment: I am not sure, if `System.out.println(...)` will work if playing with Android. use `Log.d("Title", str)` instead. It will display a message in your logcat console

Comment: mhmm..still not working. Even Log.d prints out : yes . Maybe a bug?

Comment: you changed `System.out.println("ok")` to `Log.d("Title", "ok")` ? try changing `str=="yes"` to `"yes".equals(str)`

Comment: Or dont. Use the debugger and examine the value. Adding code for simpe checks like this is prone to cause more problems than it solves. Set a break point at the return parse. Check. Done. No need for rebuilds or adding and removing code which can bring in heisenbugs.